# tortoisegit: Setting path to git.exe to an invariable destination

Tags: tortoisegit

we are using tortoisegit 2.11.0 and the PATH variable at windows is pointing to the standard installation path at c:\Program Fles.....  Can't change this because of system rights!

Now, our git.exe to use is located on a network storage! So I changed the path to the git.exe in the options dialog to the network location.
Everything fine!

But from time to time the path suddenly changed to the standard git-installation path?

The problem occures if the network storage is not avaliable or the tortoise client ist started a little bit before the netword drive is connected!

So how can I set the path to git.exe to an invariable destination that tortoise will not change it automatically back if the source is not available?
Is there a parameter in the .gitconfig or somewhat?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TortoiseGit 2.13 there is no way to disable the Git.exe detection mechanism.

It tries to find a git.exe on the path and looks for the installation path of the Git for Windows bundle if not Git.exe is configured yet.

The path is stored in registry, maybe you can create a `.reg` file to set it back (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\TortoiseGit`; `MSysGit`).

It might help not to have another git installation available on the system.